# rsync 'No such file or directory' error

Tags: backup, rsync

**Note:** this is also posted at stackoverflow by accident

Can someone give me a hand as to why my rsync command isn't working? I can't figure out what's wrong

```
#! /bin/bash

RSYNC=/usr/bin/rsync
SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
KEY=/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
RUSER=myuser
RHOST=myhost
PORT=##
RPATH=/backup-test
LPATH=/mnt/Files_Local/backup/VPS

$RSYNC -avvvz -H --numeric-ids -e $SSH -i $KEY -p $PORT $RUSER@$RHOST:$RPATH $LPATH --delete
```

All I keep getting is the following error:

```
rsync: link_stat "/backup/Friday.tar.bz2" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1518) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

**EDIT:** here is the output of ls /backup-test

```
ls -al /backup-test/
total 2402976
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root       4096 May 17 12:27 ./
dr-xr-xr-x. 25 root root       4096 May 17 11:37 ../
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2460634814 May 17 12:58 Friday.tar.bz2
```

**EDIT2:** In case it helps, here is the tar script to originally create the archive

```
tar -cjvf /backuptest/archive/$(date '+%A').tar.bz2 /backup --overwrite
```

Comment: Could `/backup/Friday.tar.bz2` be a symlink to something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Where are your quotes?

Comment: What quotes Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams? Do you mean around the source? I have tried with and without - same result

Comment: `rsync: link_stat "/backup/Friday.tar.bz2"` is not the same as `ls -al /backup-test/` -- make sure your production/development names wind up checking out. I've made this kind of mistake a bunch of times. I notice it, and mention it because your output from your script doesn't match the posted script.

Comment: Thanks dougBTV I just noticed that too. The thing is, my script clearly says to connect to {host}:/backup-test .... but rsync is trying to download from /backup/ ?? Maybe it doesn't like directories with hyphen?

Comment: ...hmm nope, I just renamed /backeup-test to /backuptest and updated my rsync script. Still getting the same error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test with Directly Rsync, without Bashscript?

Comment: Turns out my .bashrc alias was pointing to an older script in a different directory (ooops) - I have updated and the rsync is no connected....but bringing up a different error